# If $x^a \equiv x^b \bmod p$, what can we say about $a$ and $b$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If $x^a \equiv x^b \bmod p$, what can we say about $a$ and $b$, for $p$ prime?

Is there any way to show the relationship between $a$ and $b$ specifically? It doesn't seem to be the case that $ a \equiv b \bmod p$ for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that you can say is that the order of $x$ divides $b-a$. Relatedly, all that you know about the order of $x$ without any additional information is that it is a divisor of $p-1$.

Comment: Then what if $x$ were a primitive root mod $p$ (for example)?

Comment: Then you'd know that the order of $x$ is $p-1$.

Comment: So p-1 divides b-a in that case, implying b-a = 0 mod p-1, implying a = b mod p-1?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

By Little Fermat, 
$$\forall x\enspace  x^a\equiv x^b\mod p\iff \forall x\enspace  x^{a-b}\equiv 1\mod p\iff a\equiv b\mod p-1.$$

For a specific $x$, if you know $x$ is a primitive root of unity $\mod p$, of course you have the same conclusion.

For a general $x$, all you can say is $a\equiv b\mod o(x)$, i.e. $a\equiv b\;$ mod$\,$ a divisor of $p-1$.